Setting cover for MP4 files using Python and Mutagen failed, not working in Windows10
My code for set mp4 thumbnail
from mutagen.mp4 import MP4, MP4Cover
video_path = 'test.mp4'
thumbnail_path = 'test.png'

video = MP4(video_path)
video['\xa9nam'] = 'test' # work
video['\xa9ART'] = 'test' # work

with open(thumbnail_path, 'rb') as f:
    _cover = MP4Cover(f.read(), imageformat='MP4Cover.FORMAT_PNG')
video.tags['covr'] = [bytes(_cover)] # not work!!!

video.save(video_path)

Some information
I try the code in Windows-10 with mutage 1.47.0 and python3.11. Set cover not work(by check thumbnail in file folder), but set other info(like title) work good!
I need help for it, THX!
enter image description here

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

"Set cover not work (by checking the thumbnail in file folder)" Try renaming the .mp4 into .m4a and see if Explorer now changes the thumbnail from being a video frame into the image that you used? If not then share a link to a small MP4 file that does show its own custom thumbnail image in Windows Explorer.
